# How to send headers in order using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

They said they can send headers in order here:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#header-ordering

But for some unknown reason requests never sends headers in order.

Example code:

```
headers01 = OrderedDict([("Connection", "close"), ("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"), ("User-Agent", "SomeAgent"), ("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8"), ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"), ("Accept-Language", "Some Language")])
```

Result:

```
Connection: close

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8

User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2)

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

My request is already sent by sessions and it also not working if it's not sent by session.

Comment: "Requests is lying about they can to send headers in order?" Wat?

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: The snippet of the docs you've linked to is very clear that the [default headers](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py#L802) requests sets will keep their original order unless overridden by the session. If you've tried to do that, give a [mcve]. Otherwise, this is a rant that has no place here; raise a bug or  an existing one. Don't expect to be taken too seriously if you use [a burner account](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/5014), though.

Comment: They said they can send headers in order here:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#header-ordering
But in reality there is no evidence they can.

Comment: I tired both with session and without.

Comment: Well you've shown neither in the question, so I'd recommend reading [ask] and the other material in the [help].

Comment: they are there now.

Comment: See my answer below; pip freeze indicates requests==2.20.1 in case you want to check versions

Comment: We can all see that they *aren't* there now.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the documentation page you linked, it does indicate the limitation of default headers and the workaround...

Running this code:

```
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict
headers = OrderedDict([("Connection", "close"), ("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"), ("User-Agent", "SomeAgent"), ("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,applic
ation/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8"), ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"), ("Accept-Language", "Some Language")])
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers
r = s.get(http://localhost:6000/foo)
```

Sends:

```
GET /foo HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:6000\r\nConnection: close\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: SomeAgent\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Encoding:
 gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: Some Language\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: No module named 'collection'

Comment: Good catch, should be collections

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact wrong: header order does not matter, not according to the standards anyway https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

The point you are trying to make (i.e. why it does matter) is that browsers can (somewhat unreliably) be identified by fingerprinting based on the header order they happen to use. This is fine, but it is by no means a reason for a Python library to implement specific ordering.

That you're disappointed you won't be able to use this library to impersonate some browser or to get accurately finger-printed by this type of software is too bad, but it hardly justified the tone of the question.

The best suggestion here would be to find an alternative http request library that does allow specific header ordering and guarantees maintaining the order you provide.

Comment: Basically you mean request do lying about they can send headers in order and I should just live with it. But I do want warning others about that (which I'm not be convinced it is ture).

Comment: I think you need to read the entire section in the documentation though - or provide a code example that demonstrates the problem for us to be able to answer the question if your concern is correct. The documentation clearly specifies that the ordering will only be maintained under certain conditions - please provide a complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Also, if that is the case and you turn out to be correct in the sense that the documentation is flawed ('lying' is a bit silly) - your feedback is out of place and you should probably contact the maintainers of the library or its documentation to correct the mistake.